# Slowly scroll in python selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

```
url = correct_url(url)
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="New chat"]').click()
drawer_body = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('drawer-body')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', drawer_body)
```

> Get the 'div' element, this has a list and will be scrolled

drawer_body = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('drawer-body')

> The line below scrolls very fast and reaches the bottom but this does not load data. Is there any way I can slowly scroll into drawer_body element?.

browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', drawer_body)

I am trying to implement the below script using python and selenium.
http://ctrlq.org/code/19966-whatsapp-phone-numbers

Comment: When you scroll into the `drawer_body` element it makes a request to the server, you can fetch what request that is. Open the network tab and try to request the link manually and see what happens, if you provide the url I can take a look at it

Comment: I didn't get what you meant, I am new to these things.
I want to scroll in web.whatsapp.com

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers support *Spacebar* key as a keyboard shortcut for scrolling page down. Using this feature, you can do the following:

1. Visit page
2. Parse what is loaded so far
3. Simulate press spacebar using Selenium
4. Wait 2-3 seconds till more data is loaded
5. Continue

One more hint: to avoid being stuck in a forever loop, you need to implement a check if the newly loaded data differs from the one before pressing spacebar, otherwise the script should quit, as there is no new data to parse.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
drawer_body = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('drawer-body')
location = drawer-body.location
for i in range(location['x']//500):
    browser.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 500)')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 500)')
driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 500)')
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 500)')
driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 500)')
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 500)')
driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 500)')
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 500)')
driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 500)')
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 500)')
time.sleep(1)
```